# SQLitedatabase every username has the same list

Tags: android, listview, sqlite

In my application's database I have 2 tables one called "PLAYERS" which holds the data of every user and "FRIENDSLIST" which is intended to be a personal "friends" list for every registered account.How the process goes in my app is that when a player (Joe) registers a Username his information goes into the "PLAYERS" table and now he could go into my FindFriends activty,search the app for his friend's Username (Bob) and then clicks the ADD button.

The friend (Bob) then gets added to the "FRIENDSLIST" table.When he goes into the PlayAFriend activity a list will load showing the "friends" that he added.All this works good until I realized that when I log into one of his friend's account (Bob) ,that friend has the same list that (Joe) has.

I know that the cursor I'm using to load up (Joe)'s friends list is the same cursor I'm using to load up (Bob)'s friends list so the question I'm asking is,

how would I make Joe and Bob have their own personal friends list?

I've tried searching on this website and googling to find any examples on how to accomplish this but I find it crazy that I'm not finding any tutorials or posts on this subject even though this type of practice is used in every popular app made.Sorry for the long post I know it's not a simple question so that's why I had to explain in detail on what the problem is.

I'm posting up my DBAdapter class to show if how I made it would accommodate this and my PlayAFriend class to show my Cursor and ListView in action.

DBAdapter class

```
package com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBAdapter {
    static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";

    static final String KEY_USERNAME = "USERNAME";

    static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "PASSWORD";

    static final String KEY_EMAIL = "EMAIL";

    static final String KEY_NUMBERINPUT = "NUMBERINPUT";

    static final String KEY_SCORE = "SCORE";

    static final String KEY_FRIENDS = "FRIENDS";

    static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "NFDatabase";

    static final String DATABASE_TABLE1 = "PLAYERS";

    static final String DATABASE_TABLE2 = "FRIENDSLIST";

    static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;

    static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE1 = "create table PLAYERS ( _id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "USERNAME text not null unique,PASSWORD text not null,EMAIL text,NUMBERINPUT text,SCORE text);";

    static final String DATBASE_CREATE_TABLE2 = "create table FRIENDSLIST (_id integer primary key autoincrement,"
            + "FRIENDS text not null,USERNAME text ,NUMBERINPUT text,SCORE text);";

    final Context context;

    DatabaseHelper DBHelper;

    static SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE1);
                db.execSQL(DATBASE_CREATE_TABLE2);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion
                    + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PLAYERS");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS FRIENDSLIST");
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }

    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLiteException {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    // PLAYERS TABLE CRUD

    public long insertPlayer(String Username, String Password, String Email) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put("USERNAME", Username);
        initialValues.put("PASSWORD", Password);
        initialValues.put("EMAIL", Email);

        db.insert("PLAYERS", null, initialValues);

        return db.insertWithOnConflict("PLAYERS", null, initialValues,
                SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
    }

    public boolean deletePlayer(long id) {
        Log.d(TAG, "delete is working");
        return db.delete("PLAYERS", KEY_ROWID + " = " + id, null) > 0;

    }

    public Cursor getAllPlayers() {
        return db.query(false, "Players", new String[] {
                "_id", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD", "EMAIL"
        }, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    }

    public String getData() {
        String[] columns = new String[] {
                "_id", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD"
        };
        Cursor mCursor = db.query("PLAYERS", columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        String result = "";
        int iRow = mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iName = mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_USERNAME);

        for (mCursor.moveToFirst(); !mCursor.isAfterLast(); mCursor.moveToNext()) {
            result = mCursor.getString(iRow) + " " + mCursor.getString(iName) + "/n";
        }
        return result;
    }

    public Cursor getPlayer(int _id) throws SQLException {
        Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, "PLAYERS", new String[] {
                "_id", "USERNAME"
        }, KEY_ROWID + " =  " + "_id", null, null, null, null, null);
        while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {
            int id = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    public String getUsername(String Username) {
        Cursor mCursor = db.query("Players", new String[] {
            "USERNAME"
        }, "USERNAME = ?", new String[] {
            Username
        }, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor.moveToNext())
            return mCursor.getString(0);
        else
            return "";
    }

    public String getSinlgeEntry(String Username) {
        Cursor cursor = db.query("PLAYERS", null, " USERNAME=?", new String[] {
            Username
        }, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.getCount() < 1) // UserName Not Exist
        {
            cursor.close();
            return "NOT EXIST";
        }
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String password = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
        cursor.close();
        return password;
    }

    public boolean updatePlayer(long _id, String Username, String Password, String Email) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put("USERNAME", Username);
        args.put("PASSWORD", Password);
        args.put("EMAIL", Email);
        return db.update("PLAYERS", args, KEY_ROWID + " = " + _id, null) > 0;
    }

    // FRIENDS TABLE CRUD

    public void insertFriend(String Friend) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put("FRIENDS", Friend);
        db.insert("FRIENDSLIST", null, initialValues);
    }

    public boolean deleteFriend() {
        return db.delete("FRIENDSLIST", KEY_ROWID + " = " + "_id", null) > 0;
    }

    public Cursor getAllFriends() {
        return db.query(false, "FRIENDSLIST", new String[] {
                "_id", "FRIENDS"
        }, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public Cursor getFriend(long rowid) throws SQLException {
        Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, "FRIENDSLIST", new String[] {
                "_id", "FRIENDS"
        }, KEY_ROWID + " =  " + "_id", null, null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    public boolean updateFriend(long _id, String Friends) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put("FRIENDS", Friends);

        return db.update("FRIENDSLIST", args, KEY_ROWID + " = " + _id, null) > 0;
    }

}
```

PlayAFriend Class

```
package com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PlayAFriend extends ListActivity {

    DBAdapter DBAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.playafriend);

        final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
        DBAdapter = db.open();

        getListView().setAdapter(new FriendsListAdapter(this, db.getAllFriends()));

    }

    private class FriendsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener, ListAdapter {
        private Cursor fFriends;

        private Context fContext;

        public FriendsListAdapter(Context context, Cursor friends) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            fContext = context;
            fFriends = friends;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return fFriends.getCount();
        }

        @Override
        public FriendInfo getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (fFriends.moveToPosition(position)) {
                String name = fFriends.getString(fFriends.getColumnIndex("FRIENDS"));

                return new FriendInfo(name);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            fFriends.moveToPosition(position);
            return fFriends.getLong(fFriends.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(fContext).inflate(R.layout.playafriendlistitems,
                        parent, false);
            }
            FriendInfo friendinfo = getItem(position);
            TextView friendTV = ViewHolder.get(convertView, R.id.textview_friends);
            Button playbutton = ViewHolder.get(convertView, R.id.playbutton, position);
            playbutton.setOnClickListener(this);

            friendTV.setText(friendinfo.getName());

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(fContext);
            db.open();
            int position = (Integer)v.getTag();
            fFriends.moveToPosition(position);
            long id = fFriends.getLong(fFriends.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            fFriends = db.getAllFriends();
            db.close();
        }

    }

}
```

New DBAdapter

```
package com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBAdapter {
    static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";

    static final String KEY_USERNAME = "USERNAME";

    static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "PASSWORD";

    static final String KEY_EMAIL = "EMAIL";

    static final String KEY_NUMBERINPUT = "NUMBERINPUT";

    static final String KEY_SCORE = "SCORE";

    static final String KEY_FRIENDS = "FRIENDS";

    static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "NFDatabase";

    static final String DATABASE_TABLE1 = "PLAYERS";

    static final String DATABASE_TABLE2 = "FRIENDSLIST";

    static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 9;

    static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE1 = "create table PLAYERS ( _id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "USERNAME text not null unique,PASSWORD text not null,EMAIL text,NUMBERINPUT text,SCORE text);";

    static final String DATBASE_CREATE_TABLE2 = "create table FRIENDSLIST (_id integer primary key autoincrement,"
            + "player_id integer not null references PLAYERS(_id) on update cascade on delete cascade,"
            + "FRIENDS text ,NUMBERINPUT text,SCORE text);";

    final Context context;

    DatabaseHelper DBHelper;

    static SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE1);
                db.execSQL(DATBASE_CREATE_TABLE2);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion
                    + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PLAYERS");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS FRIENDSLIST");
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }

    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLiteException {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    // PLAYERS TABLE CRUD

    public long insertPlayer(String Username, String Password, String Email) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put("USERNAME", Username);
        initialValues.put("PASSWORD", Password);
        initialValues.put("EMAIL", Email);

        db.insert("PLAYERS", null, initialValues);

        return db.insertWithOnConflict("PLAYERS", null, initialValues,
                SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
    }

    public boolean deletePlayer(long id) {
        Log.d(TAG, "delete is working");
        return db.delete("PLAYERS", KEY_ROWID + " = " + id, null) > 0;

    }

    public Cursor getAllPlayers() {
        return db.query(false, "Players", new String[] {
                "_id", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD", "EMAIL"
        }, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    }

    public String getData() {
        String[] columns = new String[] {
                "_id", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD"
        };
        Cursor mCursor = db.query("PLAYERS", columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        String result = "";
        int iRow = mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iName = mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_USERNAME);

        for (mCursor.moveToFirst(); !mCursor.isAfterLast(); mCursor.moveToNext()) {
            result = mCursor.getString(iRow) + " " + mCursor.getString(iName) + "/n";
        }
        return result;
    }

    public Cursor getPlayer(int _id) throws SQLException {
        Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, "PLAYERS", new String[] {
                "_id", "USERNAME"
        }, KEY_ROWID + " =  " + "_id", null, null, null, null, null);
        while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {
            int id = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    public String getUsername(String Username) {
        Cursor mCursor = db.query("Players", new String[] {
            "USERNAME"
        }, "USERNAME = ?", new String[] {
            Username
        }, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor.moveToNext())
            return mCursor.getString(0);
        else
            return "";
    }

    public String getSinlgeEntry(String Username) {
        Cursor cursor = db.query("PLAYERS", null, " USERNAME=?", new String[] {
            Username
        }, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.getCount() < 1) // UserName Not Exist
        {
            cursor.close();
            return "NOT EXIST";
        }
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String password = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
        cursor.close();
        return password;
    }

    public boolean updatePlayer(long _id, String Username, String Password, String Email) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put("USERNAME", Username);
        args.put("PASSWORD", Password);
        args.put("EMAIL", Email);
        return db.update("PLAYERS", args, KEY_ROWID + " = " + _id, null) > 0;
    }

    // FRIENDS TABLE CRUD

    public void insertFriend(long playerId, String Friend) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put("player_id", playerId);
        initialValues.put("FRIENDS", Friend);
        db.insertWithOnConflict("FRIENDSLIST", null, initialValues, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
    }

    public boolean deleteFriend() {
        return db.delete("FRIENDSLIST", KEY_ROWID + " = " + "_id", null) > 0;
    }

    public Cursor getAllFriends() {
        return db.query(false, "FRIENDSLIST", new String[] {
                "_id", "FRIENDS"
        }, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public Cursor getFriend(long player_id) throws SQLException {
        Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, "FRIENDSLIST", new String[] {
                "_id", "FRIENDS"
        }, "player_id" + " =  " + "player_id", null, null, null, null, null);
        // cursor from query is never null,
        // should just check for if (cursor.moveToFirst()) in the calling
        // activity
        return mCursor;
    }

    public boolean updateFriend(long _id, String Friends) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put("FRIENDS", Friends);

        return db.update("FRIENDSLIST", args, KEY_ROWID + " = " + _id, null) > 0;
    }

    public long getPlayerId(String Username) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        long id = 0;
        Cursor c = db.query("PLAYERS", new String[] {
            KEY_ROWID
        }, KEY_USERNAME + "=?", new String[] {
            Username
        }, null, null, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            id = c.getLong(0);
        }
        c.close();
        return id;
    }

}


New PlayAFriend




package com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PlayAFriend extends ListActivity {

    DBAdapter DBAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.playafriend);

        final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
        DBAdapter = db.open();

        long player_id = 0;
        getListView().setAdapter(new FriendsListAdapter(this, db.getFriend(player_id)));

    }

    private class FriendsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener, ListAdapter {
        private static final long player_id = 0;

        private Cursor fFriends;

        private Context fContext;

        public FriendsListAdapter(Context context, Cursor friends) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            fContext = context;
            fFriends = friends;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return fFriends.getCount();
        }

        @Override
        public FriendInfo getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (fFriends.moveToPosition(position)) {
                String name = fFriends.getString(fFriends.getColumnIndex("FRIENDS"));

                return new FriendInfo(name);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            fFriends.moveToPosition(position);
            return fFriends.getLong(fFriends.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(fContext).inflate(R.layout.playafriendlistitems,
                        parent, false);
            }
            FriendInfo friendinfo = getItem(position);
            TextView friendTV = ViewHolder.get(convertView, R.id.textview_friends);
            Button playbutton = ViewHolder.get(convertView, R.id.playbutton, position);
            playbutton.setOnClickListener(this);

            friendTV.setText(friendinfo.getName());

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(fContext);
            db.open();
            int position = (Integer)v.getTag();
            fFriends.moveToPosition(position);
            long id = fFriends.getLong(fFriends.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            fFriends = db.getFriend(id);
            db.close();
        }

    }

}
```

FindFriends Activity

```
package com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Findfriends extends Activity {
    DBAdapter db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.findfriends);

        final EditText sbar = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.PlayerSeachBar);
        Button search = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Search);
        Button Add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Add);
        final TextView ResultText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ResultTextView);
        final FrameLayout ResultFrame = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.ResultFrameLayout);

        ResultFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
        db.open();

        search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String Username = sbar.getText().toString();
                String foundplayer = db.getUsername(Username);

                if (Username.equals(foundplayer)) {

                    ResultFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ResultText.setText(foundplayer);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Player Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }

        });

        Add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String Friends = sbar.getText().toString();
                long playerId = db.getPlayerId(Friends);
                db.insertFriend(playerId, Friends);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Player Has Been Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

LogCat

```
 04-22 21:11:37.834: E/SQLiteDatabase(15862): Error inserting player_id=0 FRIENDS=null
    04-22 21:11:37.834: E/SQLiteDatabase(15862): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: foreign key constraint failed (code 19)
    04-22 21:11:37.834: E/SQLiteDatabase(15862):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
    04-22 21:11:37.834: E/SQLiteDatabase(15862):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:775)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your table  `FRIENDSLIST`

```
static final String DATBASE_CREATE_TABLE2 = 
    "create table FRIENDSLIST (_id integer primary key autoincrement,"
    + "player_id integer not null references PLAYERS("_id") on update cascade on delete cascade,"
        + "FRIENDS text not null,USERNAME text ,NUMBERINPUT text,SCORE text);";
```

And when you insert

```
public void insertFriend(long playerId, String Friend) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put("player_id", playerId);
    initialValues.put("FRIENDS", Friend);
    db.insertWithOnConflict("FRIENDSLIST", null, initialValues, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
}
```

Get friends

```
public Cursor getFriend(long rowid) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, "FRIENDSLIST", new String[] {
            "_id", "FRIENDS"
    }, player_id + " =  " + "rowid", null, null, null, null, null);
    // cursor from query is never null, 
    // should just check for if (cursor.moveToFirst()) in the calling activity
    return mCursor;
}
```

In the database open method  add

```
public DBAdapter open() throws SQLiteException {
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;"); 
    return this;
}
```

Comment: There will be substantial changes in your codes. Design the right database is the most important thing in the beginning of a project.

Comment: I did all that but it seems like the users still have the same friendslist

Comment: in the getFriend the rowid should refer to the player_id, that is the _id in the player table.

Comment: Just did let me try out what you told me

Comment: Well you still have to change a bunch of thing, like getAllFriends as it is now this will get you all the rows in the table, the one I change will get you all friends for a particular player. If you want to get the name of a friend knowing the id of the friend row then create a method getFriendName(long id) where this id is the friend primary key and not the player id. You have to change your update methods too.

Comment: I got an error when I tried to add friends it's a foreign key constraint failed I posted up the LogCat plus I updated the classes too

Comment: Ok, probably the player does not exist for the id given.

Comment: Remove the column USERNAME from table FRIENDS

Comment: Change rowid to player_id in getFriend(long player_id)

Comment: I did what you told me I got a crash when I tried to add friend does the last part on the onClick for findfriends look right?

Comment: No the player id is 0 which is not good. The add have to refer to a player, you should save the username or id for this user and then when you add you either get the id of this user if you save the username or just pass the user id. I have to take a look to see what you try to do on Findfriends

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28699/discussion-between-hoan-nguyen-and-cranosaur)